# Yii2-Api: How to pass Token for the HttpBearer Filter

Tags: rest, yii, yii2, yii2-api, yii-inheritance

> Here is my Controller

```
class ClientController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'common\models\Client'; 
    public $serializer = [
      'class' => 'yii\rest\Serializer',
      'collectionEnvelope' => 'items',
  ];
    public function behaviors()
    {

        return ArrayHelper::meenter code hererge(parent::behaviors(),[
          [
            'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
        ],
           [
           'class' => CompositeAuth::className(),
           'except' => ['options'],
           'authMethods' => [
           HttpBearerAuth::className(),
             QueryParamAuth::className(),

           ],
        ],

           [
           'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
           ],
             [
              'class' => 'yii\filters\ContentNegotiator',
              'only' => ['view', 'index'],  // in a controller
              // if in a module, use the following IDs for user actions
              // 'only' => ['user/view', 'user/index']
              'formats' => [
                  'application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
              ],

          ],
           [
           'class' => AccessControl::className(),
    // We will override the default rule config with the new AccessRule class
           'ruleConfig' => [
           'class' => AccessRule::className(),
           ],
           'only' => ['create', 'delete'],
           'rules' => [[
           'actions' => ['create'],
           'allow' => true,
            // Allow users, moderators and admins to create
           'roles' => [
           User::ROLE_ADMIN
           ],
        ],

           [
           'actions' => ['delete'],
           'allow' => true,
            // Allow admins to delete
           'roles' => [
           User::ROLE_ADMIN
           ],
        ],
      ],
    ],
  ]);

  }
   public function actions(){
       $actions = parent::actions();
      unset( $actions['create']);
      return $actions;
   }
   public function actionCreate(){

       $model = new \common\models\Client();
       $transaction = Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
       try 
       {

        $model->load(Yii::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParams(), '');
        $user_create = \common\models\User::user_create($model);
        if($user_create){
           $model->user_id = $user_create->id;
          if($model->save()){
            $transaction->commit();
            return $model;
          }
        }

       }
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
          $transaction->rollBack();
          return null;
        }    
   }
```

> ```
> Here is my User Model
> ```

```
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{

    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return static::findOne(['id' => $id, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
    }
    public function generateAccountActivationToken()
    {
        $this->account_activation_token = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString() . '_' . time();
    }
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    // public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    // {
    //     throw new NotSupportedException('"findIdentityByAccessToken" is not implemented.');
    // }
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        return static::findOne(['auth_key' => $token]);
    }
    /**
     * Finds user by username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByUsername($username)
    {
        return static::findOne(['username' => $username, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by password reset token
     *
     * @param string $token password reset token
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByPasswordResetToken($token)
    {
        $expire = Yii::$app->params['user.passwordResetTokenExpire'];
        $parts = explode('_', $token);
        $timestamp = (int) end($parts);
        if ($timestamp + $expire < time()) {
            // token expired
            return null;
        }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->getPrimaryKey();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->auth_key;
        // return null;

    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        return $this->getAuthKey() === $authKey;
    }

    /**
     * Generates "remember me" authentication key
     */
    public function generateAuthKey()
    {
        $this->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomKey();

    }


    public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
            if ($this->isNewRecord) {
                $this->auth_key = \Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

> The issue here is when i send post request it return 401 error.I know
>   it is athentication error it even didnt hit the  function
>       public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
>         {
>                   return static::findOne(['auth_key' => $token]);
>         }
>       I kown the issue is here at   HttpBearerAuth::className(). How i can fix this error here is the image
>   [image]

Comment: @Muhammad Omer Aslam Have a look bro what goning wrong here.The login and sinup action in user controller working fine.If i remove the behaviour the the action create in client also working,now the issue is in access-token processing HttpBearerAuth::className().

Comment: added an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the statement

> It does not even land on the `findIdentityByAccessToken()`

From the [**`DOCS`**](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-authentication)

> After authentication, for every API
>   request, the requested controller will try to authenticate the user in
>   its `beforeAction()` step.
>
> If authentication succeeds, the controller will perform other checks
>   (such as rate limiting, authorization) and then run the action. The
>   authenticated user identity information can be retrieved via
>   `Yii::$app->user->identity`.
>
> **If authentication fails, a response with HTTP status 401 will be sent
>   back together with other appropriate headers (such as a
>   WWW-Authenticate header for HTTP Basic Auth).**

`HttpBearerAuth` extends `HttpHeaderAuth` which is an action filter that supports HTTP authentication through `HTTP Headers`, look into the source code for the [**`HttpHeaderAuth`**](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/filters/auth/HttpHeaderAuth.php#L51) function `authenticate($user, $request, $response)` you will see it gets the auth headers in the very first line

```
$authHeader = $request->getHeaders()->get($this->header);
```

and returns `$identity` only if the `authHeaders` are not `null`, otherwise it returns `null` from the `authenticate($user, $request, $response)` method and you receive a `401` error without even landing on the `findIdentityByAccesToken()`.

What you should do is

- Open `postman` and click on the `Authorization` tab

[image]

- Select the `Type` from the drop-down `BearerToken`

[image]

- on the right side add the `auth_key` from the user table for the user that you are sending the request against

[image]

- Click on the <kbd>Preview Request</kbd> Button and you will see the message request headers were updated

[image]

now if you go to the <kbd>**`Headers`**</kbd> tab that is very next to the <kbd>`Authorization`</kbd> tab you will see the `key=>value` pair of the authorization headers

[image]

Now click on send Button and see your request go I will recommend you to comment out everything from the action currently, and just add a `echo "hello";` statement to know that it landed there.

---

You can send the headers via curl for authentication in the following way

```
curl -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" 
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
-H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_TOKEN_" 
-X POST http://localhost:3000/data
```